# Pause Code execution until some variable is true

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone

I'm busy working on a windows phone application that calls a servlet that then in turns returns JSON, that then gets converted to a C# Object.

This code is executed when a user clicks a button:

```
    //Login button pressed
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Get needed variables
        Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
        string userName = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;

        if ((userName != "" || userName != null) && (password != "" || password != null))
        {
            //Log doctor in
            doctor.Login(userName, password);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please make sure all fields are filled out");
        }

        //If doctor has valid session ID, forward to search page
        if ((doctor.getOk() != "false") || (doctor.getOk() != "") && (doctor.getSessionID() != ""))
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Search.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            //MessageBox.Show("Ok: "+doctor.getOk()+"\nSessionID: "+doctor.getSessionID());
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Login failed, please check your username and password and try again");
    }
```

This is the doctor class:

```
public class Doctor
{
    string sessionID = "";
    string username = "";
    string password = "";
    string ok = "";

    public void Login(string argUsername, string argPassword){           

        if ((username != "" || username != null) && (password != "" || password != null))
        {
            //Set doctor username and password for later reference if necesarry
            this.username = argUsername;
            this.password = argPassword;

            //Url to login servlet
            string servletUrl = "http://196.3.151.36:8080/AuthService/login?u=" + username + "&p=" + password;

            //Calls Servlet
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(logonJsonDownloadComplete);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(servletUrl, UriKind.Absolute));

        }

    }

    //Converts returned Json to C# Object
    private void logonJsonDownloadComplete(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var jsonResponse = e.Result;
        var session = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Session>(e.Result);
        ok = session.ok;
        sessionID = session.sid;
        MessageBox.Show("Ok: " + ok + "\nSessionID: " + sessionID);
    }

    public string getOk()
    {
        return this.ok;
    }

    public string getSessionID()
    {
        return this.sessionID;
    }


}
```

This is the session class:

```
public class Session
{
    public string sid { get; set; }
    public Account account { get; set; }
    public string ok { get; set; }
    public string expiry { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem: When the user clicks the login button a new doctor object gets created, the login() method is then called on that doctor object that then in turn calls the servlet. When the json was successfully downloaded the **logonJsonDownloadComplete** method gets called in the doctor class. That then basically takes the json, and converts it to a session object that pretty much just has a bunch of getters and setters. AND THEN the login method sets the doctors variables (sessionID and ok) to whatever is now in the session object. (phew!)

But when I call the getOk() and getSessionID() on my doctor object in the button click event it returns blank strings like the variables was never set. I think this is because the code perhaps runs asynchronously?

How do I pause my code in the onclick method before the getOk() and getSessionID() statements until the **logonJsonDownloadComplete** method is called. Which means that the values have been received... if that makes sense?

### EDIT

Also probably worth mentioning that when I call the MessageDialog in the logonJsonDownloadComplete method it works, but when I call it in the click event (currently commented out) it returns the blank variables.

Comment: Why don't you make the web service be called synchronously?

Comment: @Furqan: WP7 is all async-based. You can't do any synchronous network IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to *actually* pause the code in your UI thread. What you want is for normal UI events (repainting etc) to occur, but for some/all other controls to be disabled until the login has completed.

Basically when writing WP7 apps, you *have* to think asynchronously. You're not really doing `Login` - you're doing `BeginLogin`. You need to hand the method a callback to execute when the call has completed, with the relevant results... and at that point you proceed to the next screen or whatever.

Note that asynchrony is currently relatively cumbersome, but with C# 5 and .NET 4.5, it'll become a *lot* simpler via the `async`/`await` feature.

Comment: So what you're saying is that. In my logonJsonDownloadComplete method, right at the end put in a statement like loginComplete(); where login complete is a method that then reads the corresponding sessionId and forwards to the required page?

Comment: @DeanGrobler: No, your `Doctor` class (or better, a `DoctorLoginService` class) should expose an event for `LoginComplete` which the UI can subscribe to. Or you could pass the callback into the `Login` method. The `Doctor` business object shouldn't know about the page transition - all it knows about is successful/failed login.

Comment: I see! Is it possible to call "NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Search.xaml", UriKind.Relative));" from another class in your code other than the page.xaml.cs class?

Comment: @DeanGrobler: You *could*, but you shouldn't - or rather, it's fine from the ViewModel, but not from the Model itself, assuming you're following MVVM.

Comment: Ok.. What do you mean when you say that your UI should 'subscribe' to a method/function? Sorry, I don't want to turn this thread into some long discussion.

Comment: @DeanGrobler: If you expose an event, you'd subscribe to the event. Otherwise, you'd just pass in a callback. It's up to you which model you use. (For example, `WebClient` is event-based, `WebRequest` takes callbacks in its methods.)

Comment: Thank you for your input. Could you perhaps point me to a tut that explains this "publishing and subscribing" crystal clear? Can't wrap my mind around this concept. This whole concept is basicaly delegates right?

Comment: @DeanGrobler: It sounds like you need to put down Windows Phone 7 and read an introductory C# book, to be honest - paying particular attention to event handling. I have an article about events and delegates which you may find useful in the meantime though: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx - although it assumes you have *some* experience with events in general...

Comment: Lol thanks for the honesty. Like I said before, I'm a java developer, never coded in C# in my life. I actually have a book next to me here that explains event handling and delegates etc. Thanks again, I'll go read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an Action delegate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

here, I made an example:

```
    public void IsStringEmpty(string input, Action<bool, Exception> callback)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) callback(true, null);
            else callback(false, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            callback(false, ex);
        }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        string test = string.Empty;

        // show busy indicator here

        IsStringEmpty(test, (result, error) =>
        {

            //hide busy indicator here

            if (error == null)
            {
                if (result) { /* string is empty */}
                else { /* string is not empty */}
            }
            else
            {
                /* show/log error?*/
            }
        });
    }
```